# How do I select Safari instead of Chrome as the default browser for the iOS Stack Exchange app?

Tags: support, ios-app

How do I select Safari instead of Chrome as the default browser for the iOS Stack Exchange app?

I feel like I've looked through every option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not in the app itself, but in the general Settings app of iOS. You'll find Stack Exchange in the list of apps, and if you select it, the option 'Use Chrome (if installed)' will be available.

[image]